# Headache with dynamic ng-include

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I know that `ng-view` is better for this type of problem, but I'm already using it to dynamically load an `auth` vs. `dashboard` template, so I'm stuck using `ng-includes`.

Basically, once I load the `dashboard` template with `ng-view`, I have a tab control that should change the `ng-include` depending on which tab is active.  However, I can not for my life figure out **how to change the ng-include depending on which tab is selected**.  As an FYI, super new to Angular, mostly a JQuery guy, *(and yes, I know I should avoid using JQuery w/ Angular so that I can master Angular, but I'm at my wits end with this thing)*.

**Here's my tab control:**

```
myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [{
      url: '#/dashboard/one'
    }, {
      url: '#/dashboard/two'
    }
  }];

  $scope.activeTab = '#/dashboard/one';

  $scope.onClickTab = function(tab) {
    $scope.activeTab = tab.url;
  }

  $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.activeTab;
  }

  $scope.dashboard.url = {};
  if($scope.activeTab === '#/dashboard/one') {
    $('ng-include').attr('src', 'dashboard/one.html');
  }
  if($scope.activeTab === '#/dashboard/two') {
    $('ng-include').attr('src', 'dashboard/two.html');
  }
  }]);
```

**And here's the html:**

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
          ng-class="{active_tab:isActiveTab(tab.url)}" 
          ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">
        <a href="{{tab.url}}">
          <div class="tab-icon">
            <i ng-class="tab.icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-label">{{tab.label}}</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
      <ng-include src=""></ng-include>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**@hasH:  I tried to do something along these lines, but `$scope.dashboardPath.url` didn't seem to be the actual `src="dashboardPath.url"`.**

```
var path = currentPath;//Retrieve it.
$scope.dashboardPath={};
if(path==='/dashboard/one')
    $scope.dashboardPath.url='pageOne.html';
if(path==='/dashboard/two')
    $scope.dashboardPath.url='pageTwo.html';
```

Comment: So, you are not able to initialize properly I suppose ?

Comment: Hahaha, yeah... running into issues. Welcome back to helping the Angular newbie.  I couldn't initialize it properly, I think because `ng-include` creates a new scope, so I couldn't figure out where the code to initialize it should go.  I tried putting it in the `TabCtrl`, but couldn't figure out how to access the `src` attribute.

Comment: Let me try again. As for as fixing issues. That's what SO is for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bind the src attribute of the ng-include directive with an angular expression that evalutes to `activeTab.url`.  `activeTab` is a model on the scope, and `src` will be bound to the `url` property of the model:

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="page-content">
    <ng-include src="activeTab.url"></ng-include>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your controller, make sure you assign `activeTab` to your scope:

```
   myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.tabs = [{
         url: '#/dashboard/one'
         }, {
         url: '#/dashboard/two'
      }
   }];

   $scope.activeTab = $scope.tabs[0];

   $scope.onClickTab = function(tab) {
       $scope.activeTab = tab;
   }

   $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
        return tabUrl == $scope.activeTab.url;
   }

}]);
```

There is no need to manipulate the DOM with ng-include (it would be incorrect to do so).  When 'activeTab' changes, it will automatically update ng-include because there is a binding set up between the $scope model (activeTab) and the ng-include directive.

Comment: What do you mean by "bind your ng-include with a model"?

Comment: The ng-include directive has a src attribute. The src attribute may be set to an angular expression that evaluates to a URL.  By specifying 'activeTab.url' you are binding the URL to a model (activeTab), and a property on that model (activeTab.url).

Comment: i also got this to work, but my view does not seem to be connected to its controller correctly. I can see controller events firing, but its not really connected to the view!

Answer (score 2):

As the source to the ng-include you need to bind a variable from the scope.

```
myApp.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [{
      url: '#/dashboard/one'
    }, {
      url: '#/dashboard/two'
    }
  }];

  $scope.activeTab = '#/dashboard/one';

  $scope.onClickTab = function(tab) {
    $scope.activeTab = tab.url;
    $acope.pageSource = tab.url;
  }

  $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.activeTab;
  }

  $scope.dashboard.url = {};
  if($scope.activeTab === '#/dashboard/one') {
    $scope.pageSource = 'dashboard/one.html';
  }
  if($scope.activeTab === '#/dashboard/two') {
    $scope.pageSource = 'dashboard/two.html';
  }
 }]);

<div id="wrapper" ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
          ng-class="{active_tab:isActiveTab(tab.url)}" 
          ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">
        <a href="{{tab.url}}">
          <div class="tab-icon">
            <i ng-class="tab.icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-label">{{tab.label}}</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
      <ng-include src="pageSource"></ng-include>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, been there.
Here is what I had done.

```
var controller = function($scope, $location)
{

    $scope.dashboard.url = {};

    $scope.init = function(){
        var currentLink = $location.url();


        if(currentLink === '#/dashboard/one') {
            $scope.dashboard.url = 'dashboard/one.html';
        }
        if(currentLink === '#/dashboard/two') {
                $scope.dashboard.url = 'dashboard/two.html';
        }
    };

    $scope.init();
};
```

**[EDIT] 
Maybe this could work also.**

```
var controller = function($scope, $location)
{
    $scope.tabs = [{url: '#/dashboard/one'}, 
               {url: '#/dashboard/two'}
    ];

    $scope.dashboard={};

    $scope.dashboard={url:$scope.tabs[0].url};

    $scope.init = function(){
        var currentLink = $location.url();


        if(currentLink === '#/dashboard/one') {
            $scope.dashboard = $scope.tabs[0];
        }
        if(currentLink === '#/dashboard/two') {
                $scope.dashboard.url = $scope.tabs[0];
        }
    };

    $scope.init();
};
```